# How can I constantly check if a specific key is pressed

Tags: python

I am very new to python and programming in general. I am trying to make a program that will print something if a key is pressed.
I want it to work anytime while the program is running (using `input` or `raw_input` will not work). In my IDE (**Visual Studio 2019**) the word `keyboard` is underlined in green and when I hover over it a box says `Unresolved import 'keyboard'`.

How can this be fixed?

```
import keyboard
a = True
while a:
if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
        print("Hello World")
```

Comment: It seems [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) is an third party library. Did you install it? Also if the error is only happening in the IDE but not when you run the program, you can probably ignore the error.